# How to base a style on an inherited style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

So I have a Master Detail page. And in my Master page I have a style that will set the style for all buttons.

**Master Page**

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="-0.893,-11.7"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
```

in my **Detail Page** I have a button where I would like to add some triggers to through the style

```
            <Button Content="{Binding DeleteMultipleButton}" Margin="0,0,5,0" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=files, Path=SelectedItems}" Command="{Binding DeleteMultipleFiles}">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Deleting}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>                              
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

But this overwrites the inherited style and I lose my button styling. Is there a way I can base my button style on the inherited style? (I can't do this through static resource and a key because the resource is in a different page)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to define the style with a key in `App.xaml` or a dedicated resource dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BasedOn property:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
```

Keep your base button style as it is:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="-0.893,-11.7"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
```

And apply the BasedOn property to the button on the Detail Page:

```
<Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                ...
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: I've tried this but sadly it doesn't work. this must base it on the base Button style but not the inherited button style

Comment: This probably wasn't very clear. You need to apply the BasedOn property on the style inside your Detail Page's button.

Comment: I have updated the answer for you, that should help clear things up.

Comment: I have tested this and I still can't get it to work sadly. Although this is how I would have thought to do it also

Comment: @user1 I suspect that's because the two styles are on different pages. Try putting your base style in the application's resources (usually `App.xaml`), then the button style on the detail page should "override" the base style properly.

Comment: Upvote for @MikeEason for getting the OP 90% of the way there

Answer (score 0):

So Because the two styles were on different pages it makes inheriting from the default style impossible so what I did was build an App.xaml resource file with my style in it and then on both pages add the code:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resource.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

to my xaml. This meant that my page was then able to override the inherited style by using `Mike Eason`'s code:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
```